# What's the easiest way to download all albums from Google Photos?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

I have around **950 albums** at Google Photos.

> I want to back them up now, **but organised by albums, not by date**.

Whenever I create a backup from within Google Photos, the backup splits my photos by date and adds metadata here and there.

What I am doing now is to click on every album, and choose "Download all". But this will take me ages.

**Is there a way through Google Drive or another app to have a easier job?**

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to download all albums would be to use the [Google Takeout service](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout). It can be used to export data from many Google services, including Photos. If you click the dropdown next to Google Photos in Takeout it lets you select which albums you would like to download.

Comment: But there I have around 300 Albums just with a date and not with a name. In my Album overview, I have all photos inside an album, so somehow Google messed this up. How can I fix this?

Comment: After looking through my own photos it looks like the photos in albums I have created are also in albums by date. Google can display the same data in more than one place without having more than one copy. Have you confirmed the photos in the albums with only a date do not also appear in the albums you created?

Comment: Unfortunately, without buying into a third-party app/service, this the way to go the last time I checked.   :-/