# How do I bulk download only my videos from Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos, download

I have thousands of videos and photos on Google Photos. How can I download just the videos and not the photos?

I've tried takeout.google.com, but that doesn't allow me to select *only* videos.

I know I could download everything and then manually delete the photos, but I'd prefer if there was a solution only using the Google Photos web app.

Comment: There is no way within the web app to bulk download all Google Photos content with or without filtering by file type. takeout.google.com is the best option and simply searching for and bulk-deleting the photos locally shouldn't be a significant issue.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Takeout? Seems like a good solution.  Is there a compelling reason you haven't shared why you are trying to avoid that approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/112986/ and also https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/93315/.    I know you want to filter by video but essentially it relies first on being able to download everything.  Maybe look into the options available for Takeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Photos has a help-related help article: [Download photos or videos to your device](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/7652919?hl=en). Unfortunately, this help article doesn't include instructions to download multiple videos simultaneously, only to download one by one.

Google help articles, including this one, include a Yes/No feedback question. If you click **No**, it will show a box where you can write your feedback.

The Google Photos Web app includes a help menu that includes a **Send feedback** button. You can use this option to send your feedback directly to Google.